# Regex finding the last string that doesnt contain a number

Tags: javascript, regex

Usually in my system i have the following string:

```
http://localhost/api/module
```

to find out the last part of the string (which is my route) ive been using the following:

```
/[^\/]+$/g
```

However there may be cases where my string looks abit different such as:

```
http://localhost/api/module/123
```

Using the above regex it would then return `123`. When my String looks like this i know that the last part will always be a number. So my question is how do i make sure that i can always find the last string that does not contain a number?

Comment: Which regex flavor?   Is this for sed or per or something else?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah its used in my javascript application

Comment: just try `/[^\/\d]+$/g`

Comment: Is it not simpler to use something like `url.split('/')[4]`?

Comment: `/g` makes no sense with `$`.

Comment: so in both cases, you want to macht **module**, right?

Comment: What about`([^\/]+)(?:\/[0-9]*)?$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
partYouWant = urlString.replace(/^.*\/([a-zA-Z]+)[\/0-9]*$/,'$1')
```

Here it is in action:

```
urlString="http://localhost/api/module/123"
urlString.replace(/^.*\/([a-zA-Z]+)[\/0-9]*$/,'$1')
-->"module"

urlString="http://localhost/api/module"
urlString.replace(/^.*\/([a-zA-Z]+)[\/0-9]*$/,'$1')
-->"module"
```

It just uses a capture expression to find the last non-numeric part.
It's going to do this too, not sure if this is what you want:

```
urlString="http://localhost/api/module/123/456"
urlString.replace(/^.*\/([a-zA-Z]+)[\/0-9]*$/,'$1')
-->"module"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what i came up with which really stricty matches only `module` for the following lines:

> http://localhost/api/**module**
>   http://localhost/api/**module**/123
>   http://localhost/api/**module**/123a
>   http://localhost/api/**module**/a123
>   http://localhost/api/**module**/a123a
>   http://localhost/api/**module**/1a3

```
(?!\w*\d\w*)[^\/][a-zA-Z]+(?=\/\w*\d+\w*|$)
```

### Explanation

I basically just extended your expression with negative lookahead and lookbehind which basically matches your expression given both of the following conditions is true:

1. `(?!\w*\d\w*)` May contain letters, but no digits
2. `[a-zA-Z]+` **Really, truly** only consists of one or more letters (was needed)
3. `(?=\/\d+|$)`The match is either followed by a slash, followed by digits **or** the end of the line

See this in action in my sample at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/NOyHb4/2).

Answer (score 1):

```
/([0-9])\w+/g
```

That would select the numbers. You could use it remove that part from the url. What language are you using it for ?